# Upper level seeing a lower level option

Tags: cmake

I have a lower level project that builds several libraries.  The upper level takes the libs and links them into many executables.  The lower level has this option:

```
option(TOOLA_SUPPORT "Ena/Disable toolA support" OFF)
```

I'd like to get the upper level build to see the `TOOLA_SUPPORT` flag from the lower level build.  As it is now, there are 2 `TOOLA_SUPPORT` flags.  One at the lower, the other at the upper level builds.  This is a hassle as they both need to be in the same state for a successful build.

I'm not sure how to get one CMakeLists.txt file to inherit a flag from another (cache).  (Only want this one flag, not the whole lower CMakeLists.txt/cache settings.)  What commands might help, or where to look for info?

**Edit_1**:
`dirUpper/src/CMakeLists.txt`   (Does NOT contain dirLower)  I'd like this cmakelists to "inherit" the cache var TOOLA_SUPPORT from **dirLower**/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
option(TOOLA_SUPPORT "" OFF)  
add_subdirectory(${dirLower}/src ${dirLower}/lib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
if(TOOLA_SUPPORT)
 link_directories(blah bla bla)
else()
 link_directories(blah bla)
endif()
```

`dirLower/src/CMakeLists.txt`   (Is not part of the dirUpper tree)  I'd like to pass TOOLA_SUPPORT from this cmakelists, to **dirUpper**/src/cmakelists.txt

```
IF(NOT (${COMPILER_FLAGS} MATCHES "-Wall"))  #this only applies to dirLower
 MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "compiler flag not properly set") #will crash the dirUpper 'config'
ENDIF()
OPTION(TOOLA_SUPPORT "" OFF)
IF(TOOLA_SUPPORT)
 INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(some/dir/include)
 SET(TOOLA_SUPPORT ON CACHE "" FORCE PARENT_SCOPE)
ELSE()
 MESSAGE("TOOLA is not supported")
 SET(TOOLA_SUPPORT OFF CACHE "" FORCE PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDIF()
```

When I run the dirLower file, I get a cmake warning telling me there is no parent for it.  (Not part of the dirUpper tree)
When I run the dirUpper file, I get a fatal error due to the COMPILER_FLAG test in the dirLower file.  When I bypass this issue, Im not seeing the TOOLA_SUPPORT setting being inherited from the dirLower.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lower level is "included" in the upper level with ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(), cache variables should already be shared between upper and lower.  You can use a command-line option to set the value, or use SET( ... CACHE ... FORCE) to be sure the value gets set as you actually intend.  Then just reference it from the other level.

If instead you want regular variables, it appears that regular variables set *before* the ADD_DIRECTORY() are passed down to the lower level.  And to pass a regular variable UP a level, use SET(... PARENT_SCOPE).

**EDIT:**

Writing out in code my top suggest:
In file ~/test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
OPTION(TOOLA_SUPPORT "" OFF)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test2)
MESSAGE(STATUS "${TOOLA_SUPPORT}")
```

In file ~/test/test2/CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(TOOLA_SUPPORT ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

The output is "ON".

I think the trouble you're running into is that once a cache value is set, it doesn't get changed, so the top-level value holds.  That's where the FORCE comes in.

If you're still having difficulty, please post a minimum code sample that demonstrates what's not working.

Comment: I'll guess you mean ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(), as I can't find any ADD_DIRECTORY(). The upper & lower level cmakelists.txt don't play well together.  The upper cmake is running the lower cmakelists in the scope of the upper.  i.e. None of the lower cache settings are being passed, new upper vars are being created w/ default settings. I don't want to run the lower cmakelists.txt, just grab a cache variable setting.  Is that possible?

Comment: Added more detail via edit, also fixing the ADD_SUBDIRECTORY() typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Added edit_1 above. This is my latest attempt.  I tried to describe what I am seeing. Basically, it is not doing what I want, and getting warnings along the way. (It is hard to describe.) The dir-tree issue appears to be a big deal.  Suggestions? (Thanks for your time.)

Comment: I did try your suggestion, and was not successful.

Comment: The whole point of including one from the other is that they'll share one cachefile.  In other words, build the whole thing from the toplevel.  You'll have one cache, one build directory, etc.  I still don't get where the COMPILER_FLAGS is supposed to come from, or why it wouldn't be set as expected.  I also don't see where TOOLA_SUPPORT is ever set to anything but OFF, so what's to inherit?  The IF(TOOLA_SUPPORT) means if OFF, keep it OFF.  If you want more help, fix your example to be complete and runnable, and explain what you want the output to be.